# Android Fragment click events issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am trying `FragmentActivity` instead of TabActivity in `Android 2.2`. Following is the test layout of page.
[image: Layout]
I am loading fragments run time using `FrameLayout` as container. Suppose clicking on **B1** button I am loading a Fragment **F1**, clicking on a button in **F1** Fragment loads another Fragment **F2** in FrameLayout container. Now the problem is while in Fragment **F2** and clicking on blank UI of the fragment, I am getting events of buttons that are placed in Fragment F1 on the exact location of click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I made mistake while adding new fragment, I used `Add()` method of `FragmentTrasaction` class. Instead of this method we should use `Replace()` method. Becuase `Add()` method would add your fragment to the life cycle of the containing activity. The result of this would be if you add one fregment above the other, then previous Fragement would receive click events.